# issue with encryption and decryption of a file in C with aes256-cbc using libgcrypt

Tags: c, encryption, aes

*prova* is a plaintext file that contains *hello i am a pc*

**encrypt:**

```
FILE *fp = fopen("prova", "r+");
FILE *fpout = fopen("out", "w+");
while(!feof(fp)){
    memset(plain_text, 0, sizeof(plain_text));
    retval = fread(plain_text, 1, 16, fp);
    txtLenght = sizeof(plain_text);
    encBuffer = malloc(txtLenght);
    algo = gcry_cipher_map_name(name);
    gcry_cipher_open(&hd, algo, GCRY_CIPHER_MODE_CBC, 0);
    gcry_cipher_setkey(hd, key, keyLength);
    gcry_cipher_setiv(hd, iniVector, blkLength);
    gcry_cipher_encrypt(hd, encBuffer, txtLenght, plain_text, txtLenght);
    fwrite(encBuffer, 1, 16, fpout);
}
```

**decrypt:**

```
FILE *fp = fopen("out", "r+");
FILE *fpout = fopen("origdec", "w+");
while(!feof(fp)){
    memset(plain_text, 0, sizeof(plain_text));
    retval = fread(plain_text, 1, 16, fp);
    txtLenght = sizeof(plain_text);
    encBuffer = malloc(txtLenght);
    algo = gcry_cipher_map_name(name);
    gcry_cipher_open(&hd, algo, GCRY_CIPHER_MODE_CBC, 0);
    gcry_cipher_setkey(hd, key, keyLength);
    gcry_cipher_setiv(hd, iniVector, blkLength);
    gcry_cipher_decrypt(hd, encBuffer, txtLenght, plain_text, txtLenght);
    fwrite(encBuffer, 1, 16, fpout);
}
```

**where:**

```
char key[32] = {0x80};
char iniVector[16] = {0};
char plain_text[16];
char *encBuffer = NULL;
```

**The problem:**  when i decipher the encrypted file, the file *origdec* contains the plain text plus some random useless and unreadable chars.

Comment: I'd expect the executable to segfault after printing "And I'm a Mac." `</linuxrant>`

Comment: Hint: you're not using `retval` after you assign it.

Comment: @CarlNorum i know, i'm thinking on how to use it :)

Comment: You're encrypting too much if you don't have an exact multiple of 16 characters.

Comment: have i to read the size of file and then encrypt until it the total file size is met?

Comment: Don't use `feof`, and don't ignore the `retval`!

Comment: instead of `feof` have i to use the file size (found with stat)?

Comment: You just need to regard retval as part of your calculation for length. Your first loop does iterate twice, because the first time you read 15 or 16 bytes (depending on whether there is a newline at the end of the text), and then it will run once more, probably not reading anything useful into the string, but it's encrypted. Then the decryption decrypts your "garbage" that wasn't part of the file in the first place. [Oh, and txtLenght is misspelled, should be textLength - but you should really use the value of retval, which is "how much you actually read".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you read your string,

```
fread(plain_text, 1, 16, fp);
```

you are probably getting "Hello I am a PC" (15 bytes) plus a return.

Then you encrypt 16 bytes, decrypt those 16 bytes, *and still you do not have a string terminator*, so that the printf writes extra stuff (or possibly coredumps).

You need to add a binary zero at the end of the string. Try:

```
fread(plain_text, 1, 16, fp);
plain_text[15] = 0x0;
```

and see whether this changes anything.

### UPDATE

There are several errors in your code. For example you always reinitialize the cipher, and always reallocate `encBuffer`, leading to a memory leak. I have corrected some of the bugs; there remains the feature of the encrypted file being padded to 16 bytes. There are techniques to get rid of the padding; you may want to look at PKCS#7, for example.

I have initialized arbitrarily some constants, and employed in-place encrypt/decrypt (you are not limited to a bufSize of 16; but you will have to review the padding strategy).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gcrypt.h>

int main()
{
    char iniVector[16];
    char *encBuffer = NULL;
    FILE *fp, *fpout;
    char *key       = "topolino e minni";
    gcry_cipher_hd_t hd;
    int     bufSize = 16, bytes, algo = GCRY_CIPHER_AES128, keyLength = 16, blkLength = 16;

    memset(iniVector, 0, 16);

    encBuffer = malloc(bufSize);

    fp = fopen("prova", "r");
    fpout = fopen("out", "w");

    gcry_cipher_open(&hd, algo, GCRY_CIPHER_MODE_CBC, 0);
    gcry_cipher_setkey(hd, key, keyLength);
    gcry_cipher_setiv(hd, iniVector, blkLength);

    while(!feof(fp))
    {
        bytes = fread(encBuffer, 1, bufSize, fp);
        if (!bytes) break;
        while(bytes < bufSize)
            encBuffer[bytes++] = 0x0;
        gcry_cipher_encrypt(hd, encBuffer, bufSize, NULL, 0);
        bytes = fwrite(encBuffer, 1, bufSize, fpout);
    }
    gcry_cipher_close(hd);
    fclose(fp);
    fclose(fpout);

    // Decrypt. Same algo as before

    gcry_cipher_open(&hd, algo, GCRY_CIPHER_MODE_CBC, 0);
    gcry_cipher_setkey(hd, key, keyLength);
    gcry_cipher_setiv(hd, iniVector, blkLength);

    fp = fopen("out", "r");
    fpout = fopen("origdec", "w");
    while(!feof(fp))
    {
        bytes = fread(encBuffer, 1, bufSize, fp);
        if (!bytes) break;
        gcry_cipher_decrypt(hd, encBuffer, bufSize, NULL, 0);
        bytes = fwrite(encBuffer, 1, bufSize, fpout);
    }
    gcry_cipher_close(hd);

    free(encBuffer); encBuffer = NULL;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: but if the file isn't 16 bytes?

Comment: In that case you need to get the file length with `stat()` (e.g.) and keep reading and writing. The gcrypt function will update the internal state vector as necessary. Remember that the output might be padded to the nearest larger multiple of 16, i.e., if you encrypt 17 bytes, you get 32 bytes of cyphertext.

Comment: Thanks, it works :D the only "problem" is that the decrypted file is bigger than the original... :(

Comment: That is unavoidabile, if you use a block cypher. Usually you use a removable padding such as PKCS#7 in order to recover the original file. Encrypted files will then (using e.g. AES-128) be from 1 to 16 bytes longer than the originals.

Comment: Ok thanks :) you help me a lot! Last thing: i've test aes encryption with the test vector KAT_AES.zip and all work perfectly (with strings) but how can i test if the file that i have encrypted is **correctly** encrypted with aes256?

Comment: Well... you just try to decrypt it with the same key and IV. Or, you can try and find some standard implementation of AES256 that let you specify both key and IV (most implementations generate a random IV and store it, or the information necessary to generate it, in the encrypted file). Then, use this "known-good" implementation to decrypt your file.

Answer (score 0):

Getting a decrypted file that is too large is a problem for binary files such as a database.  However, if you write the file with the real length as a prefix, you can truncate the "too big" file appropriately, assuming that the encryptor program and the decryptor program have agreed on this protocol.

I would also include the initialization vector in the prefix so that the decryptor doesn't have to guess and the two programs don't have to hard-code the IV in both programs.  So, the encryptor generates the IV with gcry_create_nonce() and the decryptor reads it from the file before decrypting the rest of the file.

How are you going to manage your secret keys?

Password-based encryption works well with the gcrypt gcry_kdf_derive() function (PBKDF2 using SHA512 w/ 128 byte salt).  Again, the salt can be generated by the encryptor and put in the front of the file; the decryptor pulls the salt from the front of the file before using it along with the same password in its gcrypt gcry_kdf_derive() call.

So, the encryptor reads cleartext and generates the following file:

```
 salt || IV || source-size || ciphertext-blocks
```

The decryptor can now reconstruct the original file.

Are you going to protect the contents with HMACs?

Have fun.

Comment: Won't truncation the file potentially lose valuable information?